# Why do we assume a module $M$ over a commutative ring $R$ to be $p$-torsion free , in some cases?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory

$(1)$ Why do we assume a module $M$ over a commutative ring $R$ to be $p$-torsion free, in some cases ?

How does it help us or how does it cost us if we don't assume it?

We know that if $M$ is $p$-torsion free module, then $pm=0 \Rightarrow m=0, \ \forall m \in M$.

So what is the benefit of assuming the above condition ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We **don't** assume modules are $p$-torsion-free **unless** (1) we're proving something that's false in the presence of $p$-torsion, or (2) we're proving something that's considerably more difficult to prove in the presence of $p$-torsion, or (3) we're proving something that's trivial in the presence of $p$-torsion, or (4) we're not interested in the case where there's $p$-torsion.

Comment: It is my mistake, in the question I should have mentioned $sometime \ p$-torsion free. Now I need  a clarification.  If $M$ be a $R$-algebra with $p^N=0$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, nilpotant,  it has also $p$-torsion. Can you explain this later case compared to my previous question ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Well if $p^N=0$, then every nonzero $R$-module has $p$-torsion, so it would be silly to talk about $p$-torsion-free modules.

Comment: if $p^N$, then every non-zero $R$-module $M$ has $p^N$- torsion (trivially), for $p^Nm=0 \ \forall m \in M$. But how does it give $p$-torsion ? i.e, how $pm=0 \ \forall m \in M$ ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR I wrote that these modules **have** $p$-torsion, which means that **some** non-zero element $m$ has $pm=0$.

Comment: I understood you. But I am saying that $p^N=0$ does not mean it is $p$-torsion free. Am I right ?